# What are the requirements to get the floor jump?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I was exploring Floor 14 and found the stairs going down to floor 15 but the floor jump didn't become enabled. now i know there was a couple of islands i hadn't mapped but i was quite sure i had mapped every possible way to the stairs

- i had found both ways to reach the island where you meet the Forrest girl
- mapped the entire southern part of the map
- mapped the most of the eastern part except for the island with the 2 alligators
- i put one of those pink flowers at every one of those flowers which you can use that i could see and an arrow in the direction it would go
- land i marked with green tiles while water i marked with blue

So i am wondering, what exactly are the requirements of getting the floor jump unlocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the floor jump for the entrance to the floor? As far as I am aware, the requirements for floor jump are to have viewed enough of a floor or specific sections of a floor (as in, no longer greyed out), and to reach one of the "intended" stairs leading downward. What I mean by that second thing is that there are a few floors later on that have multiple stairs leading down, but not all of them will enable floor jump, so if you return to those stairs after visiting the main downward staircase, they will now be able to be accessed via floorjump. I remember having the same issue with this floor, so just try experimenting with paths on the flowers to reach and map the northern sections. I believe, however, than this floor does not allow floor jump until the next floor has been cleared due to the short distance between the stairs and the boss, though I am not sure of this. If you get really stuck on how to reach the northern section, try looking at this: http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/709464-etrian-odyssey-untold-the-millennium-girl/faqs/68129 However, you still need to see enough of the floor in order to activate the floor jump, so you can't just copy the map. Good luck with Corotorangul!